# Add html to function (function.php wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add html to php function.

I added:

```
function theme_override_checkout_notes_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Podaj dodatkowe informacje odnośnie zamówienia. Jeśli wybrałeś metodę wysyłki Paczkomaty InPost lub Paczka w Ruchu to podaj adres lub kod punktu dostawy (punkty odnajdziesz poprzez powyższe linki)' ;
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Dodatkowe informacje odnośnie zamówienia. </br> <span="wysy">PODANIE PUNKTU DOSTAWY DLA PACZKOMATY INPOST, PACZKA W RUCHU</span>';
     return $fields;
}
```

In second field html does not work. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Where you are calling this function?

Comment: _“In second field html does not work”_ - that most likely means, where this value is actually used, HTML escaping gets applied. So you would have to modify the position(s) in the templates where this gets output.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you mean by "does not work". What do you expect it to do, and what is it doing instead? Are there any error messages? Also the way things are formatted people may not scroll over to the right and see that on the label line you are including html in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'theme_override_checkout_notes_fields' );

function theme_override_checkout_notes_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Podaj dodatkowe informacje odnośnie zamówienia. Jeśli wybrałeś metodę wysyłki Paczkomaty InPost lub Paczka w Ruchu to podaj adres lub kod punktu dostawy (punkty odnajdziesz poprzez powyższe linki)' ;
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Dodatkowe informacje odnośnie zamówienia. </br> <span="wysy">PODANIE PUNKTU DOSTAWY DLA PACZKOMATY INPOST, PACZKA W RUCHU</span>';
     return $fields;
}
```